# How can I configure a Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka) application to autocreate the topics in Confluent Cloud?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Is there a way to allow (Spring Cloud Stream) applications autocreate the topics they need in Confluent Cloud?

So far I've had to manually create them which is error prone when you consider you also have to setup changelog topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binder property `autoCreateTopics` is [true by default](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties). So topics should be created automatically, (unless the broker permissions don't allow it - but I would expect to see errors in the logs in that case).

There is another property `autoAddPartitions` which is false by default.

Comment: Hi Gary, apparently Confluent Cloud seems to be preventing the autocreation of topics, this is what shows up in the logs: `Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {info-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

Comment: I suggest you run in a debugger and set a breakpoint in `KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions` and step through the code. It uses an `AdminClient` to first `listTopics()` and if the topic is not present uses `createTopics()` to add it. If that fails, it logs an exception.

Comment: You were completely right. At some point I disabled automatic creation, after removing it I got the following error: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Topic replication factor must be 3`. I had to set `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replication-factor=3`. Also for changelog topics: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor=3`