# Spring cloud stream (Kafka) autoCreateTopics not working

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using Spring Cloud stream with Kafka binder. To disable the auto-create topics I referred to this- [How can I configure a Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka) application to autocreate the topics in Confluent Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532073/how-can-i-configure-a-spring-cloud-stream-kafka-application-to-autocreate-the). But, it seems that setting this property is not working and the framework creates the topics automatically.

Here is the configuration in application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.auto-create-topics=false
```

Here is the startup log

```
2021-06-25 09:22:46.522  INFO 38879 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
```

Other details-

1. Spring boot version: 2.3.12.RELEASE
2. Spring Cloud Stream version: Hoxton.SR11

Am I missing anything in this configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.auto-create-topics=false`

That property configures the binder so that it will not create the topics; it does not set that consumer property.

To explicitly set that property, also set

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.allow.auto.create.topics=false
```

Comment: Great! That worked for the consumer. Is there any way to disable this auto-create for the producer? I tried spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.allow.auto.create.topics but such property do not exist and the producer is auto-creating the missing topic

Comment: I don't see a similar property in `ProducerConfig` but I don't see the behavior you observe, I get a bunch of `[Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id xx : {source-out-0=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}` followed by a `TimeoutException` after 60 seconds.

Comment: I can see that error ```[Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {Spring-Cloud-Producer=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}``` But, it still creates the missing topic. Properties I am using are- ```spring.cloud.stream.source=producer-stream-source``` and
```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.producer-stream-source-out-0.destination=Spring-Cloud-Producer```

Comment: Sorry - you are correct, my broker had auto create disabled `auto.create.topics.enable=false`. I see it is created if the broker allows it; strange that there is not a similar property for producers. Maybe reach out to the kafka folks on one of their mailing lists?

Comment: Sorry, but how Kafka team will help me on this? Earlier I used spring Kafka where I did not face such an issue. So with the Spring cloud stream, I was hoping, there might be some configuration. The good thing is this won't be an issue in our non-prod & prod env as the auto-create topic is disabled.

Comment: `>Sorry, but how Kafka team will help me on this?` - I mean you should ask them why there is not a producer property equivalent to the consumer property. Why can't you disable `auto.create.topics.enable` on your test broker?

Comment: Sure. I will disable auto-create on test brokers. How can I get in touch with those guys? Is there any different tag on Stackoverflow for that?

Comment: Google `kafka mailing list`. Or, open a JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/

Comment: Note that `allow.auto.create.topics` property might be set for the specific consumer (through the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.configuration` section) rather than for all consumers of the binder (in the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties` section).